# Subset Sum algorithm, why not split by 3+?

Tags: combinatorics

A classic algorithm for Subset Sum is to first split the input into two sets (A and B), evaluate the sums of the subsets of each, sort those sums for each A and B, then cleverly filter whole ranges of combinations by comparing the highest and lowest sums from each A and B.

Do we know (or does someone have an argument) why not to split the input into 3 or more sets rather than two?

I presume that there would be a combinatorial proof that doing so would either require the same or more number of steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me mention that the algorithm you mention is attributed to [Horowitz and Sahni](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321823) (1974), whose algorithm achieves time $O(2^{n/2})$ and space $O(2^{n/2})$. A major improvement due to [Schroeppel and Shamir](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0210033) (1981) reduces memory consumption to $O(2^{n/4})$ while keeping the same running time; this algorithm divides the input into *four* sets.

The topic is of interest to cryptographers, and there has been a recent line of improvements: [Howgrave-Graham and Joux](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/189.pdf) (2010), [Becker, Coron and Joux](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/474.pdf) (2011), [Dinur, Dunkelman, Keller and Shamir](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/217.pdf) (2012) and [Austrin, Kaski, Koivisto and Määttä](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.0609.pdf) (2013), which seems to be the latest word on the subject; the authors of the last paper are actually not cryptographers.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question literally (which is the best option! -- and I'll mark as correct), and you've provided excellent references, but is there any reason why splitting more couldn't improve the worst-case time bound?

Comment: Either it just doesn't work, or else that's what some of these papers do.